# D3 abstract enter() method

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using D3.js, I'm trying to abstract my enter method to a function that determines if this is the first time we need to enter. Could someone please point out why this is not working?

```
  var firstRender = 0;

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("id", "circles")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .call(enterStage)  //continue chaining other D3 methods after this is ran
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d[0]);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("r", 2);


  function enterStage() {
    if (firstRender < 1) {
      firstRender++;
      return this.enter();
    } else {
      return this;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a wrapper, you can simply operate on all the selections:

```
var sel = svg.selectAll("g.circles").data([1]); // dummy data for top-level element
sel.enter().append("g")
  .attr("id", "circles");

var circleSel = sel.selectAll("circle").data(data);
circleSel.enter().append("circle");
circleSel.attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("r", 2);
```

This will work fine even the first time as the enter selection merges into the update selection when you append elements.

Comment: Beware of v4 though. This won't work as expected, because v4 no longer merges the enter selection's appends and inserts into the update selection. You will have to use [`selection.merge()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_merge) to achieve the same. I posted an explanation in my [answer](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_merge) to another question.